Flutter Read-Only Error While Writing Permission is Granted
In very short: The database is created where it should be. It is granted write permissions. I even "enforce" it. Still, I get "read-only" error while it surely shouldn't be read-only.
Long story:
Before you ask, here are the relevant logs:
I/flutter (25990): Database file successfully copied.
I/flutter (25990): Write permission verified for database file.
I/flutter (25990): Database initialized successfully at /data/user/0/com.example.color_your_world/app_flutter/data/coloryourworld.db


In the assets the db is defined also:
lib/assets/data/coloryourworld.db (shouldn't be in lib, I know. I travel between computers and not to forget to copy my assets, I put in lib folder in case. This of course will change)

Database is initialized and what not:
  runApp(
    ChangeNotifierProvider(
      create: (_) => DatabaseService(),
      child: const MyApp(),
    ),
  );


And here is my relevant database service code:
class DatabaseService extends ChangeNotifier {
  static final DatabaseService _instance = DatabaseService._internal();

  DatabaseService._internal();

  factory DatabaseService() {
    return _instance;
  }

  late Database _database;

  Future<void> initializeDatabase() async {
    final appDir = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
    final dbDir = Directory('${appDir.path}/data');
    final dbPath = '${dbDir.path}/coloryourworld.db';
...

    _database = await openDatabase(dbPath, readOnly: false);

...
  Database get database => _database;

...
Future<List<Map<String, dynamic>>> readTable(String tableName) async {
    return await _database.query(tableName);



Now. When I query, I get the following error:
Error fetching results: Unsupported operation: read-only. Am about to go mad!
I asked ChatGPT, none of its answers fixed the problem. I checked the rest of the code, everything is fine. I'm not trying to access a non-existent database, I'm not trying to read or write from/to non-existent table or "column"... Anyone has an answer? I searched the net to no avail. Hope someone will see this and
What I tried:

Of course flutter clean / pub get / run.
Making sure that the database on my computer isn't read-only. It was strange to learn that it can affect the app :)
Forcing write "rights" (code provided).
Going through the logs (I shared above, nothing wrong. Rest of the logs show nothing wrong either).
Future builder (to no avail again).
if (!await file.exists()). It does, you see/saw.
I don't use external storage as you see but I still added it in case. No use.
Try and catch while there was no need.
Rebuilding the database. Even turning to my old database. This was the strangest part: A file and code that worked the day before doesn't work now.

If will help: not all but few, very few of my data actually does show while I keep getting "read-only" error. Something somehow works but not the whole thing. I cannot have all my databases broken. Right? They all cannot be corrupt?
